# How to package express server inside electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, electron

I am currently building electron app with [vue-cli-electron-builder](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder) .
I have mysql local database and express server.

How do I bundle express server and Electron app?

- I have used express server for fetching and storing data.
- User login credentials are stored in mysql database, login form calls the express server.
- User can register with new credentials which again calls the local express server and stores in local mysql database.

It would be perfect if I could package everything inside one app and still be able to access express server.

Running electron app and the separate express server works but I want to package both electron and express so that I can perform actions only with electron app.

Comment: Looks like Electron can already do a lot of what Node can (almost like Electron is similar to Express in a sense)... https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/674#issuecomment-412344829 - there seem to be a lot of guides/questions about this online.. that's prob your best bet - just dive in and research.

Answer (score 3):

In `background.ts`, you can `import { fork } from 'child_process'`.

And put `server.js` in `/public/`.

```js
import { fork } from 'child_process'

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

const serverProcess = fork(isDevelopment 
  ? path.resolve(__dirname, "../public/server.js")
  : path.resolve(__dirname, "server.js"))

try {
  serverProcess.stdout!.on("data", console.log)
  serverProcess.stderr!.on("data", console.error)
} catch(e) {}
```

I have done it with `vue-cli-electron-builder` at some time as well, but it conflicts with Reveal.js, so I did it manually.

- [background.ts](https://github.com/patarapolw/my-notes/blob/69be1880f30d4886687e945046737e6904964633/electron/src/background.ts)
- [server.js](https://github.com/patarapolw/my-notes/blob/69be1880f30d4886687e945046737e6904964633/electron/public/server.js)

However, regarding MySQL, you shouldn't put `.env` or credentials in Electron, as people can reverse engineer it, needing a separate web server.

Comment: Came across this OP's question while researching for bundling Express and Vue in an Electron app together. However, the last part you mentioned about security consideration using this approach. Do you think it is a good idea to run Express together in an Electron app, or just run the server separately (if run locally)? Because I rarely see any tutorials that writes about this approach.